# Cookies & Webview - CookieSyncManager in Android!

Tags: android, http, cookies, authentication, webview

I have an activity that lets you sign in to a page. In the next activity it should display a webpage based on the cookie if the login was successful.
The cookie is retrived and I try to put it on the webView with the following code:

```
    Cookie sessionCookie = LoginWebView.cookie;
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webview.this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (sessionCookie != null) {
                        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName() + "=" + sessionCookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionCookie.getDomain();
        Log.v(TAG, "COOKIE SYNC: " + cookieString);
        cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookieString);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
    webView.loadUrl("http://a_page.com/getpageiphone.aspx?p=home");
```

This is losely based on code from other questions here on StackOverflow, but when I load the web-page it does not seem to work. It seems as there is something very wrong with my code but I can't see where and I'm starting to think I'm doing something very wrong.

Comment: i think you may have to set the cookie path in your cookie string. append "; Path="+sessionCookie.getPath();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have used this line -

```
 if (sessionCookie != null) {
                          cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();

  }
```

. 
To ensure you receive new cookie everytime.

Seems like you have gone through same issue as I faced, check below link -

[removeSessionCookie() issue of android (code.google.com)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16543)

it says that `removeSessionCookie()` is implemented in a thread, so whenever it is called; a thread starts and after your `setCookie(url, cookieString);` is called, it removes the new cookie you just set. 
So for some devices it works well as `removeSessionCookie()` is already executed, while, for some, it remove the cookie, and we get that problem.

by using `SystemClock.sleep(500);` , you just gave system to finish removeSessionCookie() first

I suggest you remove this `removeSessionCookie();` as you are setting only one cookie, so it won't conflict with other cookies. Your code will work seamlessly.

Comment: I too had a similar issue; seems removeSessionCookie runs in parallel to remove the newly added cookie. Thanks for this reply.

Comment: Glad that time I invested in this issue helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure to read the header values that your website gives you. You can determine this via [**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Secondly, when you know how the cookie look like (based from your Wireshark values), you should try to achieve the same values in your code. Make sure to debug the cookie's value(s) and make adjustments on the cookie itself if it doesn't match.