# Android CookieSyncManager

Tags: java, android, http, cookies

Are the cookies kept persistent when we use this? Are the cookies still available even after the phone restarts? I am referring to this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Say we are using DefaultHttpClient, CookieSyncManager would know to grab the cookies or are there other commands then the ones in the link that we will still need to provoke? How do we get the cookies back?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082799/android-how-to-store-cookies

Comment: I'm more specifically interested in the CookieSyncManager. Looking here: stackoverflow.com/a/3587332/9636 Is he using the CookieSyncManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cookies & Webview - CookieSyncManager in Android!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729266/cookies-webview-cookiesyncmanager-in-android) it seems that CookieSyncManager works with the android's built webview:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webview.this);
```

So this is not something one would use if their app is not based on the webview.

Comment: Though it can be used to assist WebViews, it is not limited to only them.  To your original question, I don't think they would persist after a phone restart, but if you need something like that, you might look into SharedPreferences.

Comment: Can it be used when making HTTP call?

Answer (score 1):

try setting CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync(); in the "onPageFinished" method, that worked for me like a charm, it mantaings the cookie even when restarted :)

here the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(web.getContext());
        web = new WebView(this);  
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl(url);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
...
```

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    }
}
```