# CookieSyncManager sync asynchronous behavior

Tags: android, android-webview

My question is pretty similar to [Cookies & Webview - CookieSyncManager in Android!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729266/cookies-webview-cookiesyncmanager-in-android), but I really need to get the `SystemClock.sleep()` time adjusted or another way to get `setCookie` react immediately. Didn't work with 500ms, but worked with 5000ms, so it's not very reliable. Any way to loop sleep in `onPageStarted` where I call `sync` for  `CookieManager` after `setCookie`?

My environment gets Cookie value from another server, so there is no session cookie here.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Looks like Cookie handling is not working at all. I have following web flow:

1. Set Cookie and load url
2. Server handles that Cookie is okay, so it adds another cookie to indicate we have a session
3. WebView still loads page showing no session
4. I start my `WebView` again, and now `getCookie` shows the session Cookie and loads page properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calling `setCookie` before I even have `WebView` present in the application(I get the Cookie value from another server), also adding in `WebViewClient` `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished`the cookie sync, it seems to be working and I didn't have to cause sleep delays.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling webview.loadUrl(url), I add a while loop to detect whether the cookie of the url has been injected. If the cookie hasn't been asynchronously set, sleep for some time. Hope it helps.

```
while (!CookieManager.getInstance().hasCookies() 
    || CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)==null){
        SystemClock.sleep(TIME_WAITING_FOR_COOKIE_SYNC);
    }
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: CookieManager here might have Cookies, but not the right Cookie, so I would remove hasCookies check and instead perform only getCookie(url) check and validate the result to not be null or empty.